# Merge multiple database table lines into one

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models, db2

**Note:** I am currently developing an application in Django using SQLite as my database, but I'm planning to migrate to IBM DB2 later, so a generic solution is preferred.

**Problem statement:** I would like to merge rows in a parent table, that will update foreign values in children tables. I am looking for a generic solution that has the best DB practices. If a solution specific to Django models is achievable, it is also valid for solving the problem.

**Example:** Suppose I have two artists in table `artist`, each one with one song each:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER REFERENCES artist(artistid) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

insert into artist(artistid, artistname) values (1, 'Prince');
insert into artist(artistid, artistname) values (2, 'The Artist (Formerly Known as Prince)');

insert into track(trackid, trackname, trackartist) values (1, 'Purple Rain', 1);
insert into track(trackid, trackname, trackartist) values (2, 'Dolphin', 2);
```

**artist**

| artistid | artistname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Prince |
| 2 | The Artist (Formerly Known as Prince) |

**track**

| trackid | trackname | trackartist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Purple Rain | 1 |
| 2 | Dolphin | 2 |

Obviously, these two artists are the same. I would like to merge both under the *Prince* entry. I can achieve this in SQLite with the code

```sql
update artist set artistid = 3 where artistid = 2; -- also updates foreign values
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;  -- disables foreign key constraints
delete from artist where artistid = 3;  -- foreign values lose reference 
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;  -- re-enables foreign key constraints
-- changes foreign values of artistid=1 AND parents formerly unparented foreign values
update artist set artistid = 3 where artistid = 1;
```

The result is

**artist**

| artistid | artistname |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Prince |

**track**

| trackid | trackname | trackartist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Purple Rain | 3 |
| 2 | Dolphin | 3 |

Although disabling and re-enabling foreign key constraints solves the problem in SQLite, I am unsure I will be able to do it in IBM DB2. Also, I would like a solution that affects only the tables that I am managing at the time, not the whole database, as `PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = OFF;` does.

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not available in DB2. Nor `TEXT` type, PK on columns that are not explicitly `NOT NULL` and `PRAGMA`. Do you need the final artistid to be 3 ? You could simply `update tracks set artist = 1 where artist = 2` and `delete artist where id = 2`.

Comment: @nfgl this is a toy example that grasps all the concepts that I have in my real problem. In reality, I have some 15 tables that depend on one parent table. I'm trying to find a (non-cumbersome) way of updating the ID on all these foreign tables without having to iterate on them